# git - how to dowload in local folder, the files from remote branch, in order to modify those files locally

Tags: git, gitlab

### context

- a remote gitlab repositary, with a master branch (default) and some ongoing feature branches from master branch, each feature branches with ongoing files inside
- a local repositary, cloned from remote, long weeks ago

### what is expected

In local command line only: update the local repositary from remote master and from remote feature branches ongoing works, in order to, first, modify locally the works done in remote branches, and secondly, send the modifications back to the remote repositary.

### what have been done

In local rep, the command `git pull --all` have been run.

### what happened, but not expected

In local rep, the folder contains update master folder and files, but does not seem to contain folders and files from remote branches.

Then, questions arrise regarding the way to work locally on remote branches files.

### question

What commands should be run locally:

- to update correctly the local repositary with the works done in the remote repositary including works done in branches ?
- to open locally the files coming from remote branches ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I've read it sounds like you've done everything right, but you're local "working tree" is still pointed at the master branch.  For argument's sake let's suppose you have a feature branch called `foo` upstream.  The local commands should look something like this.

```
$ git pull --all  # You've done this
$ git checkout foo
$ git status
```

The status command will tell you which branch you have checked out.  Additionally, Git will re-arrange the files on the *local* filesystem to match the tip of the branch.  In your case, you'll need to do this for each feature branch you need to work with.

---

As an aside, if you happen to be used to branching concepts from traditional, centralized VCS (like SVN), then Git branching may feel a bit alien at first because Git branches are really just lightweight pointers to specific commits.  So you'll only see the files and folders associated with your currently checked out branch.  While this may be unfamiliar territory if your VCS background is traditional, many people regard Git branches to be one of its best and most distinguishing features.